# Display minor matrix 3 x 3

Tags: java, matrix

I want to display minor of a matrix.
First, I have a matrix 3 x 3.

> 1  2  3
>
> 4  5  6
>
> 7  8  9

I want to display M11 (delete row 1 and col 1) so it's like

> 1  3
>
> 7  9

But with my program I got something like this

> 1  2
>
> 4  0

Here is my code :

```
    public static double [][] Minor (double [][] M, int bar, int kol, int maxidx){
        double [][] minor = new double [2][2];
        int mini=0, minj=0;
        for (int i=0; i<2;i++){
            for (int j=0;j<2;j++){
                if (i!=bar | j!=kol){
                    minor[mini][minj]=M[i][j];
                    minj++;
                    if (minj==(maxidx-1)){
                        mini++;
                        minj=0;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return minor;
    }
```

For display the minor I used this code :

```
for (int i=0;i<2;i++){
    for (int j=0;j<2;j++){
        System.out.print(Minor(M,1,1,3)[i][j]+" ");
    }
        System.out.println();
}
```

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: I think your M11 matrix would be row1- `1  3`, row2- `7 9`

Comment: your code is computing the minor again and again for every item to be displayed.

Comment: also, doing for (i) and for(j) loops just to pick 4 items seems overcomplicated.

Comment: @NandkumarTekale Yes. I'm sorry.

Comment: @sylvainulg I don't get what you said.

Comment: @husnul: my answer below should clarify my point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 if (i!=bar | j!=kol)
```

this | is bitwise operator not logical operator
however, your whole logic is wrong

do this

```
for (int i=0; i<=2;i++){
         if(i!=bar)
         {
            for (int j=0;j<=2;j++){
                if (j!=kol){
                    minor[mini][minj]=M[i][j];
                    minj++;
                    }
                }
            mini++;
         }
       }
 }
```

Comment: I have try a new logic as you said and I found it. Thanks man.

Answer (score 0):

I think this `if (i!=bar | j!=kol){` is a problem. You should use || (logic or)

Answer (score 0):

You are using bitwise `OR` where you should be using logical `AND`:

```
            if (i!=bar && j!=kol){
                       ^^
```

Right now you are only skipping the element at the intersection of `bar` and `kol`. Instead, you want to be skipping the entire `bar` row and the entire `kol` column.

Answer (score 0):

As said in comments, that sounds overkill to loop through the 3x3 matrix just to pick numbers into a 2x2.

```
/** ?skip : which is the first row/column we should keep (0/1)
 ** ?last : shall we skip the last item of the row/column.
 **/

public static double [][] MyMinor (double [][] M, int vskip, int vlast, int hskip, int hlast){
    double [][] minor = new double [2][2];
    int mini=0, minj=0;
    minor[0][0]=M[vskip][hskip];
    minor[0][1]=M[vskip][2-hlast];
    minor[1][0]=M[2-vlast][hskip];
    minor[1][1]=M[2-vlast][2-hlast];

    return minor;
}

// to remove any bar/kol combo:
MyMinor(input,bar==0?1:0,bar==2?1:0,kol==0?1:0,kol==2?1:0);
```

Answer (score 0):

First if we are trying to remove middle row and column I think your expected result would be:

1 3

7 9

So then I would say this is the code you are looking for:

```
public static double [][] Minor (double [][] M, int bar, int kol, int maxidx){
    double [][] minor = new double [2][2];
    int mini=0, minj=0;
    for (int i=0; i<3;i++){
        for (int j=0;j<3;j++){
            if (i!=bar && j!=kol){
                minor[mini][minj]=M[i][j];
                minj++;
                if (minj==(maxidx-1)){
                    mini++;
                    minj=0;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return minor;
}
```

Problem was with for loops: for (int i=0; i<2;i++) and for (int j=0;j<2;j++). As you can see it would never reach 3rd row and column in M so you will not be able to have result you expect. And also in your code

if (i!=bar | j!=kol)

should be replaced with

if (i!=bar && j!=kol) as you do not need any elements from both 'bar' row and 'kol' column.